# How to combine Material UI's HOC together

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, material-ui

Currently trying to combine multiple material UI components so that they render. At the moment, I have :

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withTheme()(withStyles(styles)(ShopStore)));
```

And this works. But now, I want to add a new HOC, which is Material UI's withWidth HOC. And I have tried a variety of locations to inject this HOC but each of those attempts just results in the whole component itself not showing up on the page. I have done research and seen that others have suggested to others to use a third party library called compose. However, it is preferred not to use that. If there is any other way to accomplish this, please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[React specifically recommends](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-maximizing-composability) a compose utility function for circumstances like this:

> The compose utility function is provided by many third-party libraries including lodash (as lodash.flowRight), Redux, and Ramda.

```
export default compose(
 connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)
 withTheme(),
 withStyles(styles),
 withWidth()
)(ShopStore)
```

Where compose looks [like this](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/compose.ts#L46) (from redux):

```
export default function compose(...funcs: Function[]) {
  if (funcs.length === 0) {
    // infer the argument type so it is usable in inference down the line
    return <T>(arg: T) => arg
  }

  if (funcs.length === 1) {
    return funcs[0]
  }

  return funcs.reduce(
    (a, b) =>
      (...args: any) =>
        a(b(...args))
  )
}
```